# HTTP 408 response in iOS extension on device, but not in Simulator

Tags: ios, alamofire

I've written an iOS share extension that takes an image and uploads it via POST request to a given URL using the code below. I'm using Alamofire to create the upload request in the background after the extension exits.

When I do this on the simulator everything works fine, I can see the image data received by requestb.in. But when I run on a device, requestb.in shows nothing at all. I pointed the URL at my own server instead, and I see an HTTP 408 response in the nginx `access.log` - but again, only when running from a device. Posting from the simulator works fine.

I was originally not specifying the threshold in the call to `Alamofire.upload` but I read the documentation above that method and thought it would be worth trying to lower that so that the file isn't streamed from memory, but it had no effect.

What could be happening that's different on the device versus the simulator?

```
guard let imageData = NSData.init(contentsOf: url) as Data? else { return }

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "image")
    }, usingThreshold: 100_000,
       to: "https://requestb.in/1egcmqq1?inspect",
       method: HTTPMethod.post,
       headers: nil) { (encodingResult) in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
```

Edit: Thanks @Yepher for the comment. I first changed the data to be just a string, which worked, and then a very small image, which also worked. So the issue seems to be related to the size of the file. I think I'm probably not doing something right related to the threshold parameter...

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you try and post hard-coded data? I expect the issue is actually related to the NSData content from URL. Have you tried to set a breakpoint there and make sure the NSData contains what you expect it too?